# is there an optimal way to serialize a query as xml and to get the rows count, both using only one statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, rowcount

Writing a SQL Server database object, I was faced with the problem of to serialize some data to XML and to get the count of rows being serialized.

I wrote something like this using a CTE:

```
-- Way III
begin    
    declare @TmpUno as table (
        uno int, dos varchar(max)
    )
    declare @RC int 
    declare @XmlSerializedData xml

    insert into @TmpUno (uno, dos)
    values (1, 'uno'), (2, 'dos')

    -- Way III :
    -- * Serialization data is stored in a local variable
    -- * Rows count is stored in a local variable
    ;with c1 as 
    (
        select uno, dos
        from @TmpUno 
    )
    select 
        @XmlSerializedData = (select * from c1 for xml path('row')),
        @RC = (select count(1) from @TmpUno)
    -- But is this the optimal way?

    select 'Way III:' as way, 
           @XmlSerializedData as [@XmlSerializedData], 
           @RC as [@RC] 
end
```

For a small table and low number of requests, that would be enough to solve the problem, but consider now to evaluate if this is this the optimal way. Execution plan look like this

Showing that, in effect two table scans are performed (circled blue)

[image]

For optimization, my question: ¿Is there a way to serialize and to count the rows being serialized, and store both results (the xml, and the rouwcount) into script local variables using only one statement, or performing only one table scan?

Comment: You can use insert into TmpUno (uno, dos)
    values (1, 'uno'), (2, 'dos') Set @RC = @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: There is no query syntax that will count the rows going into the UDX operator and then make that available to you in a variable - except if you were to actually capture the execution plan and parse that - which I'm not suggesting

Comment: You could just assign to @XmlSerializedData and then do `SELECT @RC = COUNT(*) FROM @XmlSerializedData.nodes('row') n(n)` to get the count but may well be more expensive than the double scan

Comment: You can also do this: select @rc = (DATALENGTH(CAST(@XmlSerializedData AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(CAST(@XmlSerializedData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), N'<row>', '')))  / 10

Comment: @MartinSmith `.value('count(row)', 'int')` might be the more obvious verion of that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `@@ROWCOUNT` if you are storing the data in a variable, or if you are using the `,TYPE` clause. It won't work, you will just get `1`.

Instead, you could count the nodes inside the XML

```sql
declare @RC int, @XmlSerializedData xml;

set @XmlSerializedData =
(
    select uno, dos
    from @TmpUno
    for xml path('row'), type
);

set @RC = @XmlSerializedData.value('count(row)', 'int');
```

A more efficient version is to assign each XML node a row-number, then just select the last node's number.

```sql
declare @RC int, @XmlSerializedData xml;

set @XmlSerializedData =
(
    select
      uno,
      dos,
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn)
    from @TmpUno
    for xml path('row'), type
);

set @RC = @XmlSerializedData.value('(row[last()]/RowNumber/text())[1]', 'int');
```

You could even modify this second option to get the row-number in the XML just once, and not within any `<row>` node.

```sql
select @XmlSerializedData =
(
    select
      uno as [row/uno],
      dos as [row/dos],
      RowNumber =
             CASE WHEN
                  LEAD(0) OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) IS NULL  -- no later row
             THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) END
    from @TmpUno
    for xml path(''), type
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/lz67JE_V)

Answer (score 2):

For the top level `FOR XML` statement rows get output to a top level `XML SELECT` operator and `@@ROWCOUNT` is set accordingly.

When you assign it to a variable they get collapsed down to 1 by the UDX operator and `@@ROWCOUNT` doesn't return what you need.

[image]

I can't think of any sensible possibility to get these rows counted along the way in the yellow highlighted portion of the plan and surface this up without altering the XML.

A non sensible method is below though for "fun" (depends on elevated permissions and brittle execution plan details as well as lightweight query profiling infastructure being enabled)

### A way that technically works but which I do not recommend!

```
;with
 c1 as (select uno, dos
          from @TmpUno )
  SELECT @XmlSerializedData = XmlSerializedData, 
         @RC = row_count
  FROM (VALUES((select * from c1 for xml path('row'), type))) V1(XmlSerializedData)
  LEFT JOIN (VALUES ((SELECT row_count FROM sys.dm_exec_query_profiles WHERE session_id = @@SPID  and physical_operator_name = 'Table Scan'))) rc(row_count) ON 1 = 1
  OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use @@rowcount.  eg

```
select top 1000 * 
from sales.Customer
for xml path 

select @@rowcount rows
```

This will send an XML stream to the client followed by a single-row single-column resultset.

Comment: But how to store the resulting xml into a local variable (as on the example script), whithout performing an aditional table scan ?

Comment: You'd have to store the result rows or the XML in a local variable and then query that, like you were doing.

Comment: Doesn't work if you use `,TYPE` or if you store it in a variable, you only get 1 for rowcount

Comment: That’s what TYPE means: don’t send the XML to the client; spool it to an XML variable.

Comment: Not quite: it means turn it into an `xml` typed *value*. You don't need to store it in a variable to use it, you can feed it direct to the client.

Comment: Yes, but with TYPE the client gets a single-row result set with an XML column.  So the document has to be assembled in memory, just like assigning it to an XML variable.  Without TYPE the client gets a single-column, multi-row result set that streams the XML as it's produced without assembling it on the server.